# TypeError: Cannot read property 'addListener' of undefined Error: spawn /bin/sh EMFILE

Tags: node.js

I'm getting this error:

```
Caught  signal; preparing to exit; please wait for 5 seconds
[TypeError: Cannot read property 'addListener' of undefined]
Caught  signal; preparing to exit; please wait for 5 seconds
{ [Error: spawn /bin/sh EMFILE]
  code: 'EMFILE',
  errno: 'EMFILE',
  syscall: 'spawn /bin/sh',
  path: '/bin/sh' }
```

I'm getting log just before this code. 
Actually 100's of requests to read some files is being received by the Nodejs server. **What could be the problem?**
I've checked the max process limit which is kernel.pid_max = 32768. And it is spawning fewer than 2000 processes actually. I can see `open files` limit in my my account is already 15000.

```
var path = null;
if (request.FileType & requestTypeEnum.LocalProgramFileOnly)
    {
        path = "../readfile  ";
    }
else
    {
        path = "../File-loggedin/readfile  ";
    }

var cmd = path +
        tmpobj.name +
        " recognize " +
        (request.isfirefox ? "1" : "0") +
        "  " + logobj.name + " " + resobj.name;
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec(cmd,
        function (error, stdout, stderr)
            {

                if (error !== null)
                    {

                        console.log(request.cid + "closing the connection");

                    }

                require("fs").readFile(resobj.name, 'utf8', function (err, data)
                    {

                        if (err)
                            {
                                throw err;
                            }

                        //Write into the database                            
                        store_request_db_success(request, 'File_Actual_LocalSoftware', null, db_params, data);
                        deduct_balance(request, FileCompanies.LocalSoftware);
                        var ret = getInitializedResponseData(request);
                        ret["decoded_File"] = {
                            File: data,
                            s_reqno: request.s_reqno
                        };
                        try
                            {
                                conn.sendText(JSON.stringify(ret));
                            }
                        catch (err)
                            {
                                console.log(request.cid, err);
                            }

                    });
            });
```

### ulimit -a

```
 core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 48033
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 15000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 48033
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it was more than 15000 open file descriptors which touched the limit.

I've just added `tmpobj.removeCallback();` just after `conn.sendText` when sending the response. Then the file descriptors are closed when work is done.

The `tmpobj` was created using `tmp.fileSync`